# Converting C# Cryptography.Rijndael encryption to Javascript (pref. crypto-js)

Tags: javascript, c#, cryptojs, rijndael

I have two system which are sharing a user database, so authentication needs to be the same.

The passwords are currently encrypted using C#'s `Cryptography.Rijndael`(N.B. **not** RijndaelManaged). Using a custom key and iv (initialisation vector). (CBC mode and Pkcs7 padding)

The C# encryption is as follows:

```
Rijndael alg = Rijndael.Create();
alg.Key = key;
alg.IV = IV;
CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, alg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
cs.Write(clearData, 0, clearData.Length);
cs.Close();
byte[] encryptedData = ms.ToArray();
```

`key` is 256 bits (32 bytes) and `iv` (initialisation vector) is 128 bits (16 bytes). The block size is 128 bits (16 bytes).

key and iv are a byte arrays from a base64 strings via:

```
byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Key);
byte[] iv = Convert.FromBase64String(base64IV);
```

N.B. I have no control on the C# code (legacy system).

On the javascript based system I have to encrypt the passwords exactly the same way. I've tried using node `crypto-js` to no avail.
my code looks something like this:

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(password), keyCodeWords, {
    iv: ivCodeWords,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
```

keyCodeWords and ivCodeWords are CryptoJS code words from the same base64 key and iv as follows:

```
var keyCodeWords = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(base64Key);
var ivCodeWords = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(base64IV);
```

The encryption does work (in the sense that I can encrypt and then decrypt to get the same value). However, the issue is that the encrypted value (`encrypted.ciphertext`) is not the same as the C# one, so I'm unable to authenticate.

The comparison is done base comparing the base64 encrypted output strings.

**How do I make crypto-js (or any other javascript encryption library) consistent with C# Rijndael?**

Comment: There are a million options for Rijndael in C#. Which were yours? Can you show us the code? Have you checked that the encoding fits? Remember that AES is only a subset of Rijndael. If you're using a block size other than 128 bit in C#, then you can't use CryptoJS.

Comment: You should never encrypt your user's passwords. You need to use hashing instead with some strong ones being PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Since hash functions are one-way function, you won't be able to "decrypt" the hashes. In order to authenticate your user, you can run the password through the hash function again in order to compare with the hash that is stored in the database. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Comment: @ArtjomB. , C# encryption:
`Rijndael alg = Rijndael.Create();
            alg.Key = key;
            alg.IV = IV;
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, alg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cs.Write(clearData, 0, clearData.Length);
            cs.Close();
            byte[] encryptedData = ms.ToArray();`

The `key` is 256 bits, the `iv' is 128 bits. Block size is 128.

 Unfortunately, I have no control on the C# implementation (legacy system) - I also would have just used hashing.

Comment: @ArtjomB., sorry about that I edited my question. Please check it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, it looks fine. So it must be an encoding problem. How are you encoding the password string into bytes on both sides? How are you providing the key and IV from C# in CryptoJS? Can you provide the corresponding code? How are you comparing the results?

Comment: I'm using base64 encoding. I have updated my question to show how I convert from base 64. I'm just using equality to compare the result. But since it's base 64 I can even see visually that they aren't the same.

Comment: You are absolutely correct @ArtjomB. , the issue is the encoding. The encoding on C# is using `Encoding.Unicode`. I'm using Utf8 in CryptoJS. But now the issue is I can't find Unicode encoding under `CryptoJS.enc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code works correctly... Your problem is probably in the handling of the password/IV in C# or in Javascript... In C#: https://ideone.com/APC4MM and in Javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/jjwy5472/

I've used in both cases the same password:

```
byte[] key = new byte[] 
{ 
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
    0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F,
    0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17,
    0x18, 0x19, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x1C, 0x1D, 0x1E, 0x1F,
};

byte[] iv = new byte[] 
{ 
    0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27,
    0x28, 0x29, 0x2A, 0x2B, 0x2C, 0x2D, 0x2E, 0x2F,
};
```

the plaintext is

```
"Hello world! This is a wonderful day! àèéìòù"
```

and in both cases the resulting encrypted text is

```
aa429aa5c1c928b86d81b43ff3fb6cc46f24cc73957bc7c00829357bf441eb3be9cf8aef2ff6f819f9b95c69886b169b6959c4f7ece0620c6a28f849516adee9
```

But note that the `encrypted` variable in Javascript is a complex object, containing various properties with various versions of your encrypted data. `encrypted.toString()` returns the base64 version of the encrypted data, `encrypted.ciphertext` is a `WordArray` (the equivalent of CryptoJS of `byte[]`), and `encrypted.ciphertext.toString()` is the hex version of it (equivalent to doing `BitConverter.ToString(encryptedData).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant()` in C#).

Comment: this helped me very much. I was able to see where the issue is. It's the encoding, indeed when using utf8 encoding as you did, the results are the same. However, I just noticed on my side the Unicode is used as the encoding standard on the C# version I have. Now I'm struggling to find a Unicode encoding on CryptoJS. Once I can find that and confirm that I have the same results I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Kholofelo You must use `CryptoJS.enc.Utf16LE`. See examples: https://ideone.com/lRG126 and https://jsfiddle.net/am216ywd/

Comment: @Kholofelo Note that `CryptoJS.enc.Utf16LE` could not be included in the "base" library you use of CryptoJS. It is in an additional package.

Comment: This absolutely helped, I didn't know that Utf16LE is the same as Unicode. Thanks so much @xanatos, I accepted this answer. After so long this is all I had to change!

Comment: @Kholofelo Note that "strangely" `CryptoJS.enc.Utf16 == CryptoJS.enc.Utf16BE`, so the default encoding with Utf16 is Big Endian. This is "strange" because nowadays 99% of the computers are little endian (and Windows is Little Endian). I use the double quotes around "strange" because technically the CryptoJS behavior is the more correct one (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte_order_encoding_schemes), but sometimes "correctness" and "what persons assume" are different things :-)

Comment: Your solution helped me a lot. I spent 2 days trying to resolve this issue.