# Mismatch AES 128 cypher text between iOS app and Node.js server

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, encryption, aes

On iOS app I successfully encrypt/decrypt a string using AES128 algorithm and PKCS7 padding. I have used several AES online tools to encrypt/decrypt but the results are not the same. For example: http://www.txtwizard.net/crypto

For testing purposes I am using:

1. string to encrypt: You will find the ruby at position (x,7)
2. key: sec_key_16_bytes
3. iv: ivr_key_16_bytes

On iOS I obtain the string encrypted (base64):  AAAAABAAAABwhAlwAQAAQGSHCxTygRNNvTrRNPtV6SV4eRSAkMyyToXq9XN6cEpip8QDuoV9Bkv0phJS4pocLQ==

I would like to obtain same result on a Node.js instance or simple JavaScript on client-side.
I've looked into crypto official [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html), but it has something like

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const algorithm = 'aes-192-cbc';
const password = 'Password used to generate key';
// Key length is dependent on the algorithm. In this case for aes192
// it is 24 bytes (192 bits).
// Use the async `crypto.scrypt()` instead.
const key = crypto.scryptSync(password, 'salt', 24);
// The IV is usually passed along with the ciphertext.
const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0); // Initialization vector.
```

Here I have also salt and password, while on iOS I have only the algorithm and key.
This is the Swift code:

```
import Foundation
import CommonCrypto

// Advanced Encryption Standard (symmetric key algorithm)
// More at this great tutorial: 
http://www.splinter.com.au/2019/06/09/pure-swift-common-crypto-aes- 
encryption/

protocol Cryptable {
func encrypt(_ string: String) throws -> Data
func decrypt(_ data: Data) throws -> String
}

struct AES {
private let key: Data
private let ivSize: Int         = kCCBlockSizeAES128
private let options: CCOptions  = CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

init(keyString: String) throws {
    guard keyString.count == kCCKeySizeAES128 else {
        throw Error.invalidKeySize
    }
    self.key = Data(keyString.utf8)
}

static func test() {
    do {
        let aes = try AES(keyString: "sec_key_16_bytes")
        
        let stringToEncrypt: String = "You will find the ruby at position (x,7)"
        print("String to encrypt:\t\t\t\(stringToEncrypt)")
        
        let encryptedData: Data = try aes.encrypt(stringToEncrypt)
        print("String encrypted (base64):\t\(encryptedData.base64EncodedString())")
        
        let decryptedData: String = try aes.decrypt(encryptedData)
        print("String decrypted:\t\t\t\(decryptedData)")
        
    } catch {
        print("Something went wrong: \(error)")
    }

}
}

extension AES {
enum Error: Swift.Error {
    case invalidKeySize
    case generateRandomIVFailed
    case encryptionFailed
    case decryptionFailed
    case dataToStringFailed
}
}

private extension AES {

func generateRandomIV(for data: inout Data) throws {
    
    let string = "ivr_key_16_bytes"
    let value = string.data(using: .utf8) ?? Data()

    try data.withUnsafeMutableBytes { dataBytes in
        
        guard let dataBytesBaseAddress = dataBytes.baseAddress else {
            throw Error.generateRandomIVFailed
        }
        
//            let status: Int32 = SecRandomCopyBytes(
//                kSecRandomDefault,
//                kCCBlockSizeAES128,
//                dataBytesBaseAddress
//            )
        
        dataBytesBaseAddress.storeBytes(of: value, as: Data.self)
        
 //            guard status == 0 else {
 //                throw Error.generateRandomIVFailed
 //            }
    }

}
}

extension AES: Cryptable {

func encrypt(_ string: String) throws -> Data {
    let dataToEncrypt = Data(string.utf8)
    
    let bufferSize: Int = ivSize + dataToEncrypt.count + kCCBlockSizeAES128
    var buffer = Data(count: bufferSize)
    try generateRandomIV(for: &buffer)
    
    var numberBytesEncrypted: Int = 0
    
    do {
        try key.withUnsafeBytes { keyBytes in
            try dataToEncrypt.withUnsafeBytes { dataToEncryptBytes in
                try buffer.withUnsafeMutableBytes { bufferBytes in
                    
                    guard let keyBytesBaseAddress = keyBytes.baseAddress,
                        let dataToEncryptBytesBaseAddress = dataToEncryptBytes.baseAddress,
                        let bufferBytesBaseAddress = bufferBytes.baseAddress else {
                            throw Error.encryptionFailed
                    }
                    
                    let cryptStatus: CCCryptorStatus = CCCrypt( // Stateless, one-shot encrypt operation
                        CCOperation(kCCEncrypt),                // op: CCOperation
                        CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES),           // alg: CCAlgorithm
                        options,                                // options: CCOptions
                        keyBytesBaseAddress,                    // key: the "password"
                        key.count,                              // keyLength: the "password" size
                        bufferBytesBaseAddress,                 // iv: Initialization Vector
                        dataToEncryptBytesBaseAddress,          // dataIn: Data to encrypt bytes
                        dataToEncryptBytes.count,               // dataInLength: Data to encrypt size
                        bufferBytesBaseAddress + ivSize,        // dataOut: encrypted Data buffer
                        bufferSize,                             // dataOutAvailable: encrypted Data buffer size
                        &numberBytesEncrypted                   // dataOutMoved: the number of bytes written
                    )
                    
                    guard cryptStatus == CCCryptorStatus(kCCSuccess) else {
                        throw Error.encryptionFailed
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    } catch {
        throw Error.encryptionFailed
    }
    
    let encryptedData: Data = buffer[..<(numberBytesEncrypted + ivSize)]
    return encryptedData
}

func decrypt(_ data: Data) throws -> String {
    
    let bufferSize: Int = data.count - ivSize
    var buffer = Data(count: bufferSize)
    
    var numberBytesDecrypted: Int = 0
    
    do {
        try key.withUnsafeBytes { keyBytes in
            try data.withUnsafeBytes { dataToDecryptBytes in
                try buffer.withUnsafeMutableBytes { bufferBytes in
                    
                    guard let keyBytesBaseAddress = keyBytes.baseAddress,
                        let dataToDecryptBytesBaseAddress = dataToDecryptBytes.baseAddress,
                        let bufferBytesBaseAddress = bufferBytes.baseAddress else {
                            throw Error.encryptionFailed
                    }
                    
                    let cryptStatus: CCCryptorStatus = CCCrypt( // Stateless, one-shot encrypt operation
                        CCOperation(kCCDecrypt),                // op: CCOperation
                        CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES128),        // alg: CCAlgorithm
                        options,                                // options: CCOptions
                        keyBytesBaseAddress,                    // key: the "password"
                        key.count,                              // keyLength: the "password" size
                        dataToDecryptBytesBaseAddress,          // iv: Initialization Vector
                        dataToDecryptBytesBaseAddress + ivSize, // dataIn: Data to decrypt bytes
                        bufferSize,                             // dataInLength: Data to decrypt size
                        bufferBytesBaseAddress,                 // dataOut: decrypted Data buffer
                        bufferSize,                             // dataOutAvailable: decrypted Data buffer size
                        &numberBytesDecrypted                   // dataOutMoved: the number of bytes written
                    )
                    
                    guard cryptStatus == CCCryptorStatus(kCCSuccess) else {
                        throw Error.decryptionFailed
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        throw Error.encryptionFailed
    }
    
    let decryptedData: Data = buffer[..<numberBytesDecrypted]
    
    guard let decryptedString = String(data: decryptedData, encoding: .utf8) else {
        throw Error.dataToStringFailed
    }
    
    return decryptedString
}
}
```

The result in the iOS console is:

> String to encrypt:            You will find the ruby at position (x,7)
>
> String encrypted (base64):    AAAAABAAAABwhAlwAQAAQGSHCxTygRNNvTrRNPtV6SV4eRSAkMyyToXq9XN6cEpip8QDuoV9Bkv0phJS4pocLQ==
>
> String decrypted:         You will find the ruby at position (x,7)

How can I achieve same result with JavaScript or server-side? I am setting incorrect options in Swift CCCrypt? Are there any cross-platform solutions?

Thank you!

Comment: I can't speak to a javascript framework, but I'm currently using RNCryptor in iOS which talks to System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged instance in c# .Net.  Have you seen this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36196425/converting-c-sharp-cryptography-rijndael-encryption-to-javascript-pref-crypto

Comment: RijndaelManaged is old and non standard, don't use it. Use AesCryptoServiceProvider

Comment: Actually, the same _plaintext_ should be encrypted _differently_ by the Swift-code each time, because `generateRandomIV` generates a _different_ random IV each time. Therefore, it makes no sense to expect from the JavaScript-implementation that the result corresponds to the posted ciphertext. What the JavaScript-implementation has to do is that a message encrypted with the Swift-code can be decrypted with the JavaScript-code and vice versa (if the same key is used).

Comment: @Topaco Thank you for replying. I know that the IV is random each time. For testing purposes I am using the iv "ivr_key_16_bytes".

Comment: What I'm trying to say is this: Although the IV `ivr_key_16_bytes` is hard coded in the method `generateRandomIV`, this method currently still creates a _different_ IV each time I execute it in some playground (which finally results in the generation of a different ciphertext each time). This can easily be verified by the currently posted ciphertext: The corresponding IV is hexadecimal `00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 70 84 09 70 01 00 00 40` (which isn't the hexadecimal representation of `ivr_key_16_bytes`).